# Mirror instance not up then Principal instance was down

Tags: database, mirror

I set up a Database Mirroring follow to this artic:

[Step-by-step guide to configure Database Mirroring between SQL Server Instances in a Workgroup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suhde/archive/2009/07/13/step-by-step-guide-to-configure-database-mirroring-between-sql-server-instances-in-a-workgroup.aspx)

I have 3 PCs were join Domain. Window server 2012 R2 Standard + MS SQL 2008R2 Enterprise Edition (61 bit)

- one DC as a Witness. 10.1.1.10/24
- one as  Principal 10.1.1.12/24
- one as  Mirror 10.1.1.11/24

My build was OK but when I down the Principal instance, the Mirror not UP it was *(Mirror,Synchronized/ Restoring..)*. When I start up the Pricipal again, the field Witness on Mirror is empty.

[image]

I cannot find what's the problem and the solution? This is the first time I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just made it work.

I remove all and create again with set port 5022 for all instances instead of 5023 and 5024 as a article.

You must set diffirent port when all instances only stored in a SERVER